# How to submit two separate forms in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a registration form and would like to send the user to an optional second form after submission of the first form.

How would Rails know that the second submission is tied to the first form submission?  I sort of understand Active Record associations (has_many, belongs_to), but I don't understand sessions particularly well.

I can put the second form's values in a table with

```
class SecondFormAnswers < ActiveRecord::Base
   belongs_to :user
end
```

Does Rails automatically link the User's session from that first form submission to the second?

Comment: You can use jQuery, and using `.submit()` callback, you can send another form through it.

Answer (score 0):

You can collect attributes for an associated model via [accepts nested attributes](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/NestedAttributes/ClassMethods.html).  You can build the form using [fields for](https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for).

You can put this in the User class

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :second_form_answers
```

and then in the User form, you can use `fields_for` to collect the values via inputs.

```
f.fields_for :second_form_answers do |second_form_answer|
    second_form_answer.input :attribute
```

Then you could hide the second form on the page.  If they would like to complete the second part of the form, they could click a button and show it with JQuery.

```
$(document).on(ready, function() {
    $('.second-form-button').on('click', function() { 
        $('.second-form').show();
    });
});
```

You could also do `reject_if: :all_blank` on the accepts nested attributes.  That way if they decide not to do the second part, the nested attributes will not evaluate it if all of the inputs are blank.

```
accepts_nested_attributes_for :second_form_answers, reject_if: :all_blank
```

Comment: Will the first form still submit to the db even if the second isn't completed?

Comment: Hiding the second form on the same page was how I was thinking of doing it. I'm trying to figure out how to do it after a redirect to a second form. I appreciate the response. I may do it the way you've described since I understand it!

Comment: You could do a reject if blank on the accepts nested attributes if you don't want to worry about the second form if all of the inputs are blank.  reject_if: :all_blank I will modify the answer...

Comment: thanks Eric. I have some studying to do. You've set me down a good path. I appreciate it.

Comment: You're welcome.  Good luck!  If this works out for you, please select it as the chosen answer.

Answer (score 0):

Having a separated model for this is an awful practice.

You should save your `User.id`  into a cookie, in your controller.

Assuming that you are creating a new User:

```
class User < ApplicationController

  def create
    @user = User.create(user_params)
    session["user_id"] = @user.id

    redirect_to edit_user_path(@user)
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(session["user_id"])
    @user.update(user_params)
  end

end
```

Of course this is just for elaborating the problem solution. You should adapt it to your own logic. But maybe you could even add methods to your `ApplicationController` like `current_user` (as a helper method) to get the `User` record from the `session[:user_id]` value.

Comment: "Having a separated model for this is an awful practice." Noted. I was going to go this route again because my User could has_many Products. That wouldn't apply to this second form, though.